# Apply Superscript to all decimal digits appearing after a certain string?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, microsoft-word-2016

Suppose I have a string in Microsoft Word 2016 like this:

`道过存在Al2V3和Al50V50这两Al20种`

Now I want to select all decimal digit after `Al` like

[image]

and apply Superscript formatting to those digits?

I think I should be using Find and Replace with RegEx in Word, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The "1" same to "l" in *Times New Roman*.Sorry my English to linked a wrong documentation.You predicate the *Word* cannot do this thing?

Comment: Since you can't do multiple selections at the same time like your picture suggests you want, what is the overall goal?  Once you've selected one of these matches, what do you want to do?  Replace them all with some other text? Or?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I want to set they to be superscript in one time.

Comment: So for example, in "AI2V3" you'd want to change the formatting of "2" to superscript?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes,or you have another method?

Comment: The problem with using Word's RegEx for this is that a) The "Find" always selects the entire Find pattern, and b) You can't apply formatting like superscript to only part of the Replace pattern.  I think you'll need to write some VBA to do what you ask.

Comment: I updated your question to be more about the actual problem you're trying to solve (Superscripting those digits), instead being specific to your chosen solution (RegEx Find and Replace).  Like I said in my previous comment, you can do this, but I think you'll need to write a VBA macro to perform what you're asking, as Find and Replace can't do it.  Maybe someone else knows better and/or has the time to help you with that macro - I do not. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks,but actually if I can chosen they meanwhile,the following step is very easy.

Comment: You can do it in two steps (two Find and Replace): first change Al followed by numbers to superscript, then change Al in superscript to normal (assuming no other Al in superscript exist).

Comment: @endrju How to do the first step?

Comment: In "Find what" try: Al[0-9]@ or if this doesn't work: Al[0-9]{1,}. Make sure "use wildcards" is checked. "Replace with" leave empty, but place cursor in this field and then set format of a font in the bottom of the Find and Replace dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

At first I wanted to base the solution on regex. To write such an expression is not a big deal but *Superscript* is a property. It’s not possible to replace a property with another one using regex. Instead of  RegExp.Replace it is possible to use RegExp.Execute which finds all the occurences but this method does not save information about the position and length of each occurence.

Instead of regex I just used a loop to iterate through the whole text.
At first the code identifies what to change and in the second loop it applies the changes. It is done so as per the [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821411.aspx) „*There can be only one Selection object per document window pane, and only one Selection object in the entire application can be active.*”

```
Option Explicit
Sub toSuperscript()
    Dim al As String
    Dim alPosition As Integer
    Dim alOcc As String 'Al occurence
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strTemp_len As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim subCounter As Integer
    Dim c As New Collection 'start
    Dim c1 As New Collection 'length

    al = "Al" 'the searched string
    ActiveDocument.Select
    strTemp = Selection.Text
    strTemp_len = Len(strTemp)

    'search for Al
    For counter = 1 To strTemp_len
        alOcc = Mid(strTemp, counter, 2) '2 as Al is characters long
        If StrComp(CStr(alOcc), CStr(al), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            subCounter = 0
            Do Until IsNumeric(Mid(strTemp, counter + 2, subCounter + 1)) = False
                subCounter = subCounter + 1
            Loop
                c.Add CStr(counter + 2) 'start
                c1.Add CStr(subCounter) 'length
        End If
    Next counter

    'Apply superscript
    For counter = 1 To c.Count
         ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=c.Item(counter) - 1, End:=CInt(c.Item(counter)) + CInt(c1.Item(counter)) - 1).Font.superscript = True
    Next counter
    Application.Selection.StartOf 'Put the cursor at the beginning of the document (optional)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use VBA, you can do a two-stage find and replace.

1. Open the Replace dialog box, select the "More >>" button, and turn on wildcards.
2. Do the replacement with Find What as `Al([0-9]{1,})` and Replace as `Al++\1++`. I picked `++` as a delimiter because it almost certainly doesn't appear in your document, but you can use just about anything distinct.
3. Change Find What to `++([0-9]{1,})++` and Replace to `\1`. With your cursor still in the Replace box, go down to the "Format" menu button, select "Font...", choose "Superscript", and confirm the dialog box. Then do the replacement.

Word's wildcards are very strange if you're used to regular expressions from Unix, Perl, JavaScript, and others.

- Parentheses do act like capture groups in traditional regular expressions, and the replacement can have backreferences to them (`\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second group, etc.).
- Square brackets can only have a character range, not arbitrary characters or ranges.
- The `*` acts like it does in command line wildcards not regular expressions, so it can't be used here.
- The description of `@` leads you to believe that it's like a regular expression `+`, but it isn't, so it also can't be used here.
- Curly brackets do act like curly brackets in a regular expression, so they can be used here.